# Implementing a Fullscreen Background Video with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

Okay, to start, this may be a duplicate but I for the life of me cannot make it fit full screen on my Chromebook. As the title states, I have stripped my html site to the bare bones to debug why this video will not fill the screen.

I've tried near every stackoverflow answer, YouTube video, W3Schools article, and it will not fill the entire width. There's this small section on the right of the screen that won't fill.

Here's my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Derek Martin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
    <source src="vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</body>

</html>
```

And my CSS file:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Absolutely any pointers will be appreciated because out of all the things I cannot nail in CSS and HTML is just making a video span the entire screen.

EDIT: https://websiteportfolio.derek-martin.repl.co/
Use that to check what I am referring to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `vh` and `vw` point that are relative to screen size:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Or, you can make container (`body` tag) 100vw*100vh and your css will work.

Comment: Just attempted that and the issue still persists. I'm beginning to think it's just a issue on my Chromebook? Took a screenshot after altering my code: https://ibb.co/BLFpJPq

Comment: @DerekMartin, just looked at your code. Your video element has `id="myVideo"`, not `class="myVideo`, so styling just don't apply.

Comment: Thanks so much, got it FINALLY, you're a lifesaver man